# Magento 2.3.6: How to change shipping address country name of Taiwan instead of Taiwan, province of China?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, country-regions, name

I am using Magento2.3.6.

I want to change shipping address country name of  Taiwan instead of Taiwan, province of China. How can I update for it?
I tried to update in app/code/Magento/Config/i18n/en_US.csv. But can't.

Comment: What you want to change here `Taiwan instead of Taiwan`? I can't see any difference.

Comment: "Taiwan" instead of "Taiwan, province of China" @RahulBarot

Comment: I don't know where you want to edit it but you can try "Translate inline" feature, turn it on and translate anything visible to you

Comment: @Nang did you end up finding out how to do this? I have a new thread about this issue and i tried couple of methods, but was not able to achieve the goal of changing the country_of_manufacture attribute at all. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339436/country-of-manufacture-issues-with-names-in-magento-2

Comment: @kalving not done yet.