# country_of_manufacture issues with names in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, country-regions

I am having issues with **country_of_manufacture** attribute.

I recently made a copy of production site to prep our new server for migration from old server.

The issue comes in when I do import testing - the **country_of_manufacture** attribute is breaking the import.

```
Notice: Undefined index: czechia in /home/linux/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Type/AbstractType.php on line 537
```

The issue comes from difference in naming of **Czech Republic**.

Production site is set to **Czechia**, but NEW production is set to **Czech Republic**

I am super confused by this.

Does **store** or **locale** affect on the **country_of_manufacture** attribute?

I compared both sites and they both use the same locale and store.

Is there anything else that could be causing the difference in name of the country?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Today working on upgrade to 2.4 and now import is not working because country_of_manufacture is hitting Taiwan. Apparently in 2.4.2 its set to Taiwan, Province of China.

[image]

Looking back at the working Production with 2.3.3 its set to Taiwan

[image]

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I have tried changing the value inside of msp_tfa_country_codes and also adding a translation for the country.

After I reindexed the store and refreshed cache, but the value in the country_of_manufacture attribute did not change.

I also searched through the DB for "Taiwan, Province of China" string and it showed 0 results.

So I'm at a loss where this value is being taken from.

I even edited the vendor\msp\twofactorauth\Setup\data\country_codes.json which is the only file that had that string.

Same result.

Comment: Are the production site and the copy the same version? My production site running 2.4.2-p1 shows Czech Republic, but my local environment running 2.4.0 shows Czechia. You could change the product attribute value to Czechia and the Default Store View to Czech Republic

Comment: @Hunter yes they are both the same version. The locale is also the same: Pacific Standard Time (America / Vancouver). Both sites have the same settings and DB. The only thing different is the Base URL. I ended up just removing products that have Czech Republic as Country of Manufacture. But this is really weird stuff. I have no idea how this could happen if you cant even change this via DB.

Comment: Please try this link I guess it will helpful to you. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22180/commits/d23dd1ed5df664dcfbe79106058049e7e0b1e7fc

Comment: I was intrigued by this. My 2.4.2-p1 site is still showing Czechia

Comment: @iphigenie I wonder if there is some dependency plugin that got updated, but some one of the sites I manage did not get an updated version? Hmm. It seems strange because both got composer update ran through them.

Comment: Thats not it :(

Comment: @KalvinKlien the only thing that could perhaps be linked is the Zend framework. 
But I remember looking a while back because some of the swiss region names are wrong - countries and regions come from the "directory" tables in the database.

Comment: @KalvinKlien looking a bit more, there's no country name in those tables and not much in the magento vendor folder - so it's possible the name comes from the Zend libraries, using store locale and the stored code vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The issue is that I was translating a core translation that was already in Magento 2 core file:

```
src\vendor\magento\module-config\i18n\en_US.csv
```

The line there says:

```
"Taiwan, Province of China","Taiwan"
```

What I did is put **\i18n\en_US.csv** into one of my own modules, but I made a mistake and I was translating Magento 2 translation.

```
"Taiwan, Province of China","Taiwan"
```

to

```
"Taiwan", "Taiwan, Province of China"
```

^^^ this is incorrect.

What I should have done is translated the **original word**.

```
"Taiwan","Taiwan"
```

After this the translation showed up correctly in the Admin section:

[image: Magento 2 translation]